# How to set dynamic width of div?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

```
<div style="width:100px">
   <div id="divUserName">
     UserName
   </div>
   <div id="divCompanyName">
   CompanyName
   </div>
</div>
```

In my code UserName can be of dynamic length and same with CompanyName.
I want to set width of div as per name of UserName similarly for the
CompanyName.

Restriction is that I can only use style or css. no jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#divUserName,
#divCompanyName {
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

#divUserName {
    background-color: #f00;
}

#divCompanyName {
    background-color: #0f0;
```

```html
<div style="display: inline-block">
   <div id="divUserName" >
     UserName
   </div>
   <div id="divCompanyName">
   CompanyName
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
#theparent, #divUserName, #divCompanyName { 
   display: inline-block;
   width: auto/*not neccessary*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using float property. When you use float the width will be set automatically as per data present in that.

so

```css
#divUserName{
    background:green;
    border:1px solid blue;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
}
#divCompanyName{
    background:yellow;
    border:1px solid blue;
    margin:5px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:auto;">
   <div id="divUserName">
     UserName
   </div>
   <div id="divCompanyName">
   CompanyName
   </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: But I want this in single row like UserName    CompanyName. Please suggest to make it in a single row

Comment: I have updated the above code as per your need please check it.